# SQL "select" query for getting 0 instead of null?

Tags: mysql

In the database I have some value as `null` . So while fetching these null value from database it should be treated as `0` not as `null`. 
Note:- **I don't want to be it done by code but from SQL query**.

Comment: [`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

`SELECT IFNULL(ColumnName,0) FROM TableName`

or

`SELECT COALESCE(ColumnName,0) FROM TableName`

Comment: hi @vijayp, my query returning the result with 'NULL', so I have used if(empty($resultProduct)){ } still its not empty since it is returning one row, how to avoid this one

Comment: @jafarpinjar - that looks like `php` not `sql`. Don't use `empty`. Google good way to test $resultProduct for `null`. If that is php, `is_null`. But its not clear to me that $resultProduct is a scalar value. Make sure you follow a tutorial to understand the steps of handling result of sql query in php. Start a new StackOverflow question if you can't find one (but there are many already...) Learn to use `var_dump` and `print_r` to find out what type $resultProduct is, and google how to work with that type. [I think don't continue this discussion here - beyond the scope of this Question.]